# Which parameter should be considered as "scale" parameter for Gamma distribution?

Tags: terminology, gamma-distribution

I originally posted this question on crossvalidated. In case it would be considered too "nerdy" or useless there, I also posted it here with the hope to get more replies.

---

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) and probably all statistics textbooks, we know that in the density of a Gamma random variable
$$f(x; k, \theta) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)\theta^k}x^{k - 1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}, \quad x > 0; \theta > 0, k > 0, \tag{1}$$
$k$ is called *shape* parameter and $\theta$ is called *scale* parameter. The reason that $\theta$ is referred as scale parameter is quite obvious: if $X \sim \text{Gamma}(k, \theta)$, then for any $c > 0$, $cX \sim \text{Gamma}(k, c\theta)$. In other words, for fixed $k$, the Gamma$(k, \theta)$ family is invariant under scale transformation $X \mapsto cX$. This argument makes much sense and I followed this convention for many years.

However, when I was answering [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184753/in-a-glm-is-the-log-likelihood-of-the-saturated-model-always-zero/184764#184764) question tonight and tried using Gamma distribution as an example, I found some conflict if we considered Gamma distribution as a member of exponential-family distributions. Conventionally, an exponential family has the following representation (for example, see Chapter $7$ of [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387954570)):
$$f(x; \phi, \varphi) = \exp\left[\frac{x\phi - \gamma(\phi)}{\varphi} + \tau(x, \varphi)\right].\tag{2}$$
In this representation, $\varphi$ is called scale parameter. Now let's transform $(1)$ into the form $(2)$ and see what will happen.

By letting $\varphi = \frac{1}{k}$ and $\phi = -\frac{1}{k\theta}$, $(1)$ can be written as
$$f(x; \phi, \varphi) = \exp\left[\frac{x\phi  - (-\log(-\phi))}{\varphi} -\frac{\log \varphi}{\varphi} + \left(\frac{1}{\varphi} - 1\right)\log x - \log\Gamma(\varphi^{-1})\right] \tag{3}$$

Comparing $(2)$ and $(3)$, it is that $\varphi = \frac{1}{k}$ should be called as scale parameter! So based on the nomenclature inside exponential family, it seems also makes sense to refer $k$ as scale parameter.

I understand that this small collision may be due to reparameterization and the fact the word "scale" is too busy in statistics and in probability. Can anyone give other explanations and is it possible that this unfortunate collision can be fixed? Thank you very much.

Comment: I really would just chalk it up to a reparameterization issue. I understand a gamma distribution with parameters $r,\lambda$ as $\Gamma(r)^{-1}\lambda^rx^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x}$. I wish all notations could be standardized.

Comment: I wish too. I hope one day one day all books, papers all use unique representations. However, I think the difference mentioned in my question seems slightly more serious than that the gamma distribution density you wrote in comment and equation $(1)$ in my post.

Comment: The lack of unity of notations (in statistics) occasionally annoys me. As another example, I think I have seen at least $5$ different representations for the exponential family from different books and journals, which makes me can't memorize any  of them complete correctly without the help of checking reference. How sad it is!